# Zabbix Proxy crashing daily

Tags: zabbix

We have a new install of Zabbix 3.4.7 (RHEL7) with a Proxy (RHEL6) but every day we're seeing the proxy crashing with the zabbix_proxy.log showing the following errors

> noname.xml:5: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link
>   line 4 and head  ^ noname.xml:10: parser error : Opening and
>   ending tag mismatch: head line 2 and html  ^ noname.xml:5:
>   parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 4 and head
>    ^ noname.xml:10: parser error : Opening and ending tag
>   mismatch: head line 2 and html  ^ noname.xml:5: parser error :
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 4 and head  ^
>   noname.xml:10: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: head
>   line 2 and html
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.334 Got signal
>   [signal:11(SIGSEGV),reason:1,refaddr:0x40]. Crashing ...
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.334 === Backtrace: ===
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 11: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad51a2ca]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 10: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad51a6e1]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335
>   9: /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x3f112326a0) [0x7f82a99206a0]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 8: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad4bd465]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335
>   7: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector #6 updated 0, removed 0
>   VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services
>   [0x7f82ad4bf5c8]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 6: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy:
>   vmware collector #6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008
>   sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad4c12a2]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 5: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad529fdb]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 4: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad48336b]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 3: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad5199e8]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 2: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy: vmware collector
>   6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008 sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad482832]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 1: /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)
>   [0x7f82a990cd5d]
>
> 24795:20180917:181036.335 0: /usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy:
>   vmware collector #6 updated 0, removed 0 VMware services in 0.000008
>   sec, querying VMware services [0x7f82ad481019]

We are monitoring VMWare through the proxy and it seems like the messages could 
be related.

Strangely the crashes seen to be around 18:10 each day when suggests it must be some daily check or schedule job that could be causing the problems.

Has anyone come across anything similar to this, or if not could someone give me some pointers as to where else I could look to find out what might be causing the crash?

Comment: If you can estimate the next time this could happen, bump the loglevel on proxy for the VMware collector to level 5 (runtime thing, no need to restart proxy) a few minutes before the expected crash, wait for it to crash and report a bug to Zabbix, attaching the collected logfile. But even before that consider upgrading the proxy to 3.4.14.

Comment: Thanks @Richlv. Just to confirm, is that just a case of changing the 'DebugLevel' in the zabbix_proxy.conf?

Comment: No, the suggested method is to use runtime control - run `zabbix_proxy --help` to see details. But make sure to reproduce this with the latest version first.